# General form of a double integral

Tags: integration

I have difficulty calculating the general form of a double integral:

$\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2mxy}\,\text{d}x\text{d}y$, where m is a constant between -1 and 1.

I've tried some special cases:

m=0:

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\text{d}x\text{d}y
=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4}\int_0^{\sec\theta}r^2\text{d}r\text{d}\theta
=\frac13\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4}\sec^3\theta\text{d}\theta=\frac13(\sec\theta\tan\theta+\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|)\big|_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

$$
=\frac{\sqrt2+\ln(\sqrt2+1)}{3}$$

m=1:

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1|x-y|\text{d}x\text{d}y=\frac13
$$

General cases:

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2mxy}\text{d}x\text{d}y=\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{(x-y\cos\theta)^2+y^2\sin^2\theta}\text{d}x\text{d}y
$$

I've tried to use substitution, but it seemed more complex...

Update:Actually I've tried to continue, here's what I got:

$$
\int\sqrt{(x-y\cos\theta)^2+y^2\sin^2\theta}\text{d}(x-y\cos\theta)
$$

Using substitution $x-y\cos\theta=y\sin\theta\tan u, \text{d}(x-y\cos\theta)=y\sin\theta\sec^2 u$

$$=y\sin\theta\int\sec^3 u\text{d}u=\frac12x\sec u-\frac12y\sin\theta\tan\theta+\frac12\ln|\sec u+\frac{x}{y\sin\theta}-\tan\theta|$$....

Update:

Thanks to @Po1ynomial in the comments, I tried to use polar coordinate but got stuck here:

$$2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4}\int_0^{\sec\theta}r^2\sqrt{1-m\sin2\theta}\text{d}r\text{d}\theta=\frac23\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4}\sec^3\theta\sqrt{1-m\sin2\theta}\text{d}\theta=?...$$

Comment: Why don't you continue? You can treat $y$ and $\theta$ as constants if integrating w.r.t $dx$. You can then bring the integral to the form $\int c(y) \cdot (\int \sqrt{1 + x²} dx)dy$. The inner integral can be computed 'easily' (but in order to do so you need $\sin(\theta) \neq 0$).

Comment: But yes, the results seems to be ugly.

Comment: You'll need to be careful in the case of $m>1$. For example, when $m=2$ the radicand $x^2-4xy+y^2$ vanishes along the lines $y=(2\pm\sqrt3)x$, both of which pass through $[0,1]^2$ so the integrand is not defined over the entire region.

Comment: @user170231 Sorry I didn't notice that, actually, the m in my research is $\cos\theta$, so m is between -1 and 1.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but the closed form is $\frac{1}{3} \left(\left(m^2-1\right) \left(\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1-m}{2}\right)-\log (m+1)+\log \left(2-\sqrt{2-2 m}\right)\right)-\left(\sqrt{2-2 m}-1\right) m+\sqrt{2-2 m}\right)$

Comment: @Po1ynomial Thanks, I tried some special cases, it seems your answer is right, but could you please briefly tell me how to calculate it? 

Comment: Polar coordinates directly does the job.

Comment: @Po1ynomial I tried and here's what I got:$\frac23\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4}\sec^3\theta\sqrt{1-m\sin2\theta}\text{d}\theta$ and I have no idea what to do next...

Comment: Substitute $t=\tan\theta$.

Comment: @Po1ynomial Thanks. I've worked it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Po1ynomial in the comments.

Using polar coordinates:
$$I=\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2mxy}\text{d}x\text{d}y=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4}\int_0^{\sec\theta}r\sqrt{1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta}\text{d}r\text{d}\theta=\frac23\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4}\sec^3\theta\sqrt{1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta}\text{d}\theta$$

Substitute $t=\tan\theta$:
$$I=\frac23\int_0^1\sqrt{1+t^2-2mt}\text{d}t=\frac23\int_0^1\sqrt{(t-m)^2-m^2+1}\text{d}t$$

We first consider:

$$\int\sqrt{(t-m)^2-m^2+1}\text{d}(t-m)$$

Substitute $t-m=\sqrt{1-m^2}\tan u$,$\text{d}(t-m)=\sqrt{1-m^2}\sec^2u$:

$$(1-m^2)\int\sec^3u\text{d}u=\frac{1-m^2}{2}(\sec u\tan u+\ln|\sec u+\tan u|)$$

Notice that $\sec u =\sqrt{1+\frac{(t-m)^2}{1-m^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{t^2-2mt+1}{1-m^2}}$, $\tan u =\frac{t-m}{\sqrt{1-m^2}}$:

As for the case where t=1:

$$\frac{1-m^2}{2}(\sqrt{\frac2{1+m}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1-m}{1+m}}+\ln|\sqrt{\frac2{1+m}}+\sqrt{\frac{1-m}{1+m}}|)=\frac{(1-m)^\frac32}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1-m^2}{2}(\ln(\sqrt2+\sqrt{1-m})-\ln\sqrt{1+m})$$

t=0:

$$-\frac{m}{2}+\frac{1-m^2}{2}\ln\frac{\sqrt{1-m}}{\sqrt{1+m}}$$

So:

$$I=\frac{\sqrt2}3(1-m)^{\frac32}+\frac{m}3+\frac13(1-m^2)\ln\frac{\sqrt{2(1-m)}+1-m}{1-m}$$

Answer (score 0):

To solve $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + 2mxy}dxdy$$, begin by using the completing the square method to get $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{(x^2 + 2mxy + m^2y^2) - m^2y^2 + y^2}dxdy = \int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{(x + my)^2 - m^2y^2 + y^2}dxdy$$ Now, substitute $$u = x + my, x = u - my, du = dx$$ This slightly simplifies the integral and makes a complicated trigonometric substitution possible. Now, make another substitution. This substitution is $$v = tan^-1{\frac{u}{\sqrt{y^2 - m^2y^2}}}, u = tan(v)\sqrt{y^2 - m^2y^2}, du = sec^2\sqrt{y^2 - m^2y^2} dv$$ This substitution may seem random, but it will allow the usage of the formula $$ytan^2(x) + y = ysec^2(x)$$ Now, the integral looks like this: $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\sec^2(v)\sqrt{y^2 - m^2y^2}\sqrt{(y^2 - m^2y^2)tan^2(v) - m^2y^2 + y^2} dv = \int_0^1\sqrt{y^2 - m^2y^2}\sqrt{y^2 - m^2y^2}\int_0^1\sec^3(v)dvdy$$ Finally, the reduction formula can be applied to solve the first integral. By the way, the way everything is written may look weird because I don't really know how something like this should look like. Also, another trigonomic formula is used, $$sec(tan^-1(x)) = \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$$ $$\int_0^1\sqrt{y^2 - m^2y^2}\sqrt{y^2 - m^2y^2}\frac{(sec(v)tan(v))}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1sec(v)dvdy = \int_0^1y^2-m^2y^2(\frac{(sec(v)+tan(v)}{2} * \frac{1}{2})ln(tan(v)+sec(v))dy =\int_0^1\frac{(1-m^2)y^2ln(\sqrt{\frac{(x+my)^2}{y^2-m^2y^2} + 1} + \frac{x+my}{\sqrt{y^2-m^2y^2}})}{2} + \frac{(1-m)^2y^2(x+my)\sqrt{\frac{(x+my)^2}{y^2-m^2y^2} + 1}}{2\sqrt{y^2-m^2y^2}}dy$$ Finally, plug 0 and 1 into x to finally complete the first intgral. I will do both integrals separately to save time and not write the massive integral out. The first integral is $$\int_0^1\frac{(1-m^2)y^2ln(\sqrt{\frac{(1+my)^2}{y^2-m^2y^2} + 1} + \frac{1+my}{\sqrt{y^2-m^2y^2}})}{2} + \frac{(1-m)^2y^2(1+my)\sqrt{\frac{(1+my)^2}{y^2-m^2y^2} + 1}}{2\sqrt{y^2-m^2y^2}}dy$$ Start by solving the first term in this equation. Begin by using the formula $$ln(\sqrt{x+1} + x) = sinh^-1(x) *Another update, solving this problem has taken forever, and writing it down takes even longer. I've sadly not had time to complete the problem. I'm planning to finish it over the weekend when I have more time.